# PHP Math Function Contstant E

Tags: php, math

I am having to write a conversion table as a project. However some of the numbers they give us are 4.014e+9 and 3.861e-7, along with some others that include e+ and e-. If I am wanting to multiply this by the number entered, does PHP recognize the constant E?

```
$result = "RESULT:" . $num * 4.014e+9;
```

and

```
$result = "RESULT:" . $num * 3.861e-7;
```

Or do I need to so something else for it to recognize it?

Comment: This is not the mathematical constant E, but numbers represented using stndard scientific format

Comment: Did you try it?  Does that not work?  It should work.

Comment: @Rocket The confusion is between the constant e (2.718...) and the scientific notation e, which is signifying 10 ^ x

Comment: @nickb: That doesn't answer my question of whether the posted code works or not :-P

Comment: @Rocket - Well, the code "works", but not how the OP expected because of that confusion.  </my assumption>

Comment: @nickb: If it were supposed to be the constant `E` (or `e`), then I don't think `e+9` or `e-7` would make any sense :-P

Comment: @nickb I just did a quick search for mathE and that is what came up so I was assuming it was constant. However if it is the scientific notation e then I am assuming the code is working as it should

Comment: @Conner - OK, thanks for clearing that up. Yes, scientific notation is supported in PHP, so you should be good to go!

Comment: And if it wasn't, you should be seeing a parse error instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `e` is not a constant; it's part of the [scientific notation float literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation).

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out; I was confused between constant e and scientific notation. @nickb informed me that scientific notation is supported in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work, you could always use the function [pow()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) with pow(10,$X); as a workaround. But first try the code yourself to see if it works.